# Time-independent distributions of charge and fields

Tags: electrostatics

In the introduction of Jackson "Classical Electrodynamics", the author says that the electrostatics studies phenomena that involve **time-independent** distributions of charge and fields.

For **time-independent** does Jackson intends **time-invariant**, as expressed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system)?

Comment: How do the two terms differ in your opinion?  By time-independent it is meant that the distribution does not change in time, charges are stationary at least at the macro level.  There are always quantum fluctuations as we now know.